# How do I extract information from text file using node.js

Tags: node.js

How can  i  search key words into a text  and return the data just after this key word  with node js i find it with php and c# but not with javascript or node js?

Comment: Load the file and then use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

Comment: yup Michael indexOf was the solution to verify if the word exists or not thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can implement the above scenario using node's [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module.With the help of this we can read the file's data and perform the keyword search operations on the processed data.

```
var fs = require("fs")
    fs.readFile("somefile.txt", function(err, content) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Do Required Operations with the content which is the file data 
    });
```

Comment: the problem is i can't find how to serach data into my text i don't need to return index just if the words i am looking for exist in the text then return the whole line after it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [npm config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config).

It sounds like you are trying to parse an ini file, or something like that. If so, you can use the [.properties file format](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files#properties-file-format---properties).

So assuming you store your text file as config/default.properties, you could do something like:

```
const config = require('config');
const MYVALUE = config.get('MYKEY');
```

Comment: i have a text file which is an official  contract  and i want to search key words like date , name of entreprise , name of customer ... and extract the data after it